# How to convert data to an edge list

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I'm currently analysing survey data about people's preferred music genres. I want to build a network to show which genres people often enjoy in tandem.

I'm not sure what the best way to format my data is. It's currently in a form like this:

```
         Genre A Genre B Genre C 
Person A 1       1       1
Person B 1       1       0 
Person C 1       1       0
```

Where a 1 indicates that they enjoy it, and a 0 that they don't. I'd like the network to connect genres and for the edges to show how often they're connected. I think the igraph package would work, but I need to convert my data to an edge list first.

Here's some quick code to set up the table in case you need it:

```
read.table(text = 
"GenreA GenreB GenreC 
PersonA 1 1 1
PersonB 1 1 0 
PersonC 1 1 0 
", header = TRUE)
```

I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert your data frame to a matrix, then the cross-product of this matrix will be equivalent to the adjacency matrix of the desired graph.

```r
library(igraph)

g <- as.matrix(df) |>
       crossprod() |>
       graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mode = 'undirected', diag = FALSE)
```

Now `g` is your actual graph (network object)

```r
plot(g)
```

[image]

And if you want it as an edgelist, you can do:

```r
as_edgelist(g)
#>      [,1]     [,2]    
#> [1,] "GenreA" "GenreB"
#> [2,] "GenreA" "GenreB"
#> [3,] "GenreA" "GenreB"
#> [4,] "GenreA" "GenreC"
#> [5,] "GenreB" "GenreC"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `igraph` answer, you can try base R like below as well

```
> subset(as.data.frame.table((d <- tcrossprod(t(df))) * lower.tri(d)), Freq > 0)
    Var1   Var2 Freq
2 GenreB GenreA    3
3 GenreC GenreA    1
6 GenreC GenreB    1
```